# how to change EditText hint color in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a [login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoiNq.png)

If user don't enter username or password and press "login" button, the EditText hint will warn you, like this[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2J2G.png)(turn red). How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should set error instead

```
editText.setError(getString(R.string.error_required));
```

but if you want that

```
editText.setHint()
editText.setHintTextColor
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image you have posted , it is very simple to show that hint when there is no data entered in username/password fields.

```
if(username.isEmpty())
{
  usernameEditTextView.setHint("please enter username");
  usernameEditTextView.setHintTextColor(R.color.Red);
}
```